# convert binominal to nominal in Rapid Miner

Tags: rapidminer

I have imported a dataset in which the gender (m/f) has been interpreted as "binominal". If I am not mistaken, this means that there is a mapping true/false is assigned to the two values m/f.

Since I need to find association rules, this is not correct.

My question is: is it possible to convert a binominal field to nominal and then expand it again to two nominal attributes (one for male and the other for female) in order to be correctly used with the "FP-Growth" and "Create Association Rules" operators?

Comment: -1: for questions concerning the **usage of rapidminer**, it makes more sense to ask in the rapidminer forums than a programming website. Your question should involve code, if it is posted here.

Comment: so what is code? Is it necessarily some text? Might be a diagram? If a diagram is executable then it's code and rapid miner is an interpreter of this code.

Comment: and then, by the way, why do you think that there exists a Rapidminer tag if not for doing questions about the product? And why did you remove the other tags? Once you do this at least leave a comment to explain. Since this is a subject also for machine learning and might involve decisions at theorical level.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: please reply to my comments above

Comment: Rapidminer is open source. If you have questions concerning the source code of rapidminer, then this may be an okay place to ask. It will likely still be *smarter* to ask the RapidMiner users directly on their mailing list or forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nominal to Binominal` operator has a "transform binominal" checkbox which does exactly that.

You don't have to transfer the binominal attribute to nominal first. It works even for binominal attributes on input.